# Azure SQL SCOPE_IDENTITY to create identical ID columns for different tables

Tags: sql-server

I'm bulk inserting a JSON file into a SQL db once a day. I'm trying to parse the object into 5 different tables, and in doing so, I'm trying to use the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` feature to include an ID column that will allow be to join the tables afterwards.

However, I'm only getting `null`'s when I try to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong, or if I'm even using it correctly.

This is my SQL:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(max)
    =   (   SELECT BulkColumn
              FROM
                   openrowset(BULK 'flexfoneoutputblob/data', DATA_SOURCE = 'FlexfoneBlobStorage', SINGLE_CLOB)
                   AS blob );





DECLARE @id INT 


INSERT Employee (GId,
                 LocalNumber,
                 Name,
                 Description,
                 Email)
SELECT @id,
       LocalNumber,
       Name,
       Description,
       Email
  FROM
       OPENJSON(@json)
       WITH (Localnumber INT,
             Name NVARCHAR(250),
             Description NVARCHAR(250),
             Email NVARCHAR(250)) AS G;
SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT PhoneNumbers (GId,
                     Number,
                     LineName,
                     BelongsTo,
                     GotoLocalNumber)
SELECT @id,
       Number,
       LineName,
       BelongsTo,
       GotoLocalNumber
  FROM
       OPENJSON(@json)
       WITH (PhoneNumbers NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON)
 CROSS APPLY
       OPENJSON(PhoneNumbers)
       WITH (Number NVARCHAR(20),
             LineName NVARCHAR(20),
             BelongsTo NVARCHAR(10),
             GotoLocalNumber NVARCHAR(20)) AS json;
SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
INSERT Phones (GId,
               LocalNumber,
               Name,
               Type,
               MAC,
               BelongsTo,
               description)
SELECT @id,
       LocalNumber,
       Name,
       Type,
       MAC,
       BelongsTo,
       description
  FROM
       OPENJSON(@json)
       WITH (Phones NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON)
 CROSS APPLY
       OPENJSON(Phones)
       WITH (LocalNumber NVARCHAR(20),
             Name NVARCHAR(50),
             Type INT,
             MAC NVARCHAR(20),
             BelongsTo NVARCHAR(20),
             description NVARCHAR(30)) AS go2
SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
INSERT Info (GId,
             Type,
             Label,
             Value)
SELECT @id,
       Type,
       Label,
       Value
  FROM
       OPENJSON(@json)
       WITH (Info NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON)
 CROSS APPLY
       OPENJSON(Info)
       WITH (Type INT,
             Label NVARCHAR(20),
             Value NVARCHAR(20)) AS go3
SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
INSERT Department (GId,
                   Name,
                   Street,
                   Zipcode,
                   City,
                   Cvr,
                   Contact,
                   Email,
                   Ean,
                   Iref)
SELECT @id,
       Name,
       Street,
       Zipcode,
       City,
       Cvr,
       Contact,
       Email,
       Ean,
       Iref
  FROM
       OPENJSON(@json)
       WITH (Department NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON)
 CROSS APPLY
       OPENJSON(Department)
       WITH (Name NVARCHAR(20),
             Street NVARCHAR(20),
             Zipcode NVARCHAR(20),
             City NVARCHAR(20),
             Cvr NVARCHAR(20),
             Contact NVARCHAR(20),
             Email NVARCHAR(20),
             Ean NVARCHAR(20),
             Iref NVARCHAR(20)) AS go4
SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

I want to create 5 tables `Employee`, `PhoneNumbers`, `Phones`, `Info` and `Department`.

How do I create ID columns in each tables, such that the rows correspond to their respective item in the JSON file?

Comment: The only point at which the assign is **before** your `INSERT` statements. `SCOPE_IDENTITY` gives you the value of `IDENTITY` generated in the *prior* `INSERT` in the same scope; there *was* no prior `INSERT` so of course `SCOPE_IDENTITY` will have a value of `NULL`

Comment: You, however, are turning on `IDENTITY_INSERT` prior to every `INSERT` anyway, so why do you need the value `SCOPE_IDENTITY` when *you* are defining the value you want to insert for the `IDENTITY`; you already know what the value of the `IDENTITY` is, *you* defined it in your `INSERT`.

Comment: So drop the GId column from the destination table ? I've altered the statement a bit

Comment: You've really managed to mangle [my code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705191/14868997) I'll need to give you a fuller answer there but haven't managed yet. `SCOPE_IDENTITY` isn't going to work based on that, because you have multiple items, plus any case you've put it in the wrong place.

Comment: @Charlieface - Your code helped me fetch 1 item from the array. I had multiple, so my solution was to change it to the above, which works. But I need a way to add an ID column, so I can join them together. This is where I'm fumbling...

Comment: Your problem is going to be uniquely identifying the rows. Are any of the base `Employee` columns unique within the array, perhaps `LocalNumber` or `Name`, then it's much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SCOPE_IDENTITY()` will not help, because you have multiple items in the JSON array, [as you mention in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67700227/parse-nested-json-to-azure-sql-table/67705191). You need an altogether different approach.

**One option would be to use the `OUTPUT` clause.**

Let us assume the `Name` column is unique within the array, and `Id` is the primary key. So we declare a table variable, and use `OUTPUT inserted.Name, inserted.Id INTO @tmp (Name, Id)`, this gives us pairs of `Name, Id` to join in the later queries.

In the next queries, we need to use `OPENJSON` with no schema, in order to split up the array, we then `CROSS APPLY OPENJSON` again to get the child objects, and join `@tmp` to get the parent Id.

```sql
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = (
    SELECT BulkColumn
    FROM openrowset(BULK 'flexfoneoutputblob/data', DATA_SOURCE = 'FlexfoneBlobStorage', SINGLE_CLOB)
);

DECLARE @tmp (Name nvarchar(250) PRIMARY KEY, Id int NOT NULL);

INSERT Employee
    (LocalNumber, Name, Description ,Email)
OUTPUT inserted.Name, inserted.Id INTO @tmp (Name, Id)
SELECT LocalNumber
    ,Name
    ,Description
    ,Email
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$') WITH (
        Localnumber INT
        ,Name NVARCHAR(250)
        ,Description NVARCHAR(250)
        ,Email NVARCHAR(250)
        ) AS G;

-- @tmp now contains Name and Id pairs which we can join

INSERT PhoneNumber
    (EId, Number, LineName, BelongsTo, GotoLocalNumber)
SELECT tmp.id, Number, LineName, BelongsTo, GotoLocalNumber
FROM OPENJSON(@json) arr
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(arr.[value], '$.PhoneNumbers') WITH (
        Number NVARCHAR(20)
        ,LineName NVARCHAR(20)
        ,BelongsTo NVARCHAR(10)
        ,GotoLocalNumber NVARCHAR(20)
        ) AS json
JOIN @tmp tmp ON tmp.Name = JSON_VALUE(arr.[value], '$.Name');

INSERT Phone
    (EId, LocalNumber, Name, Type, MAC, BelongsTo, description)
SELECT tmp.id, go2.LocalNumber, go2.Name, go2.Type, go2.MAC, go2.BelongsTo, go2.description
FROM OPENJSON(@json) arr
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(arr.[value], '$[0].Phones') WITH (
        LocalNumber NVARCHAR(20)
        ,Name NVARCHAR(50)
        ,Type INT
        ,MAC NVARCHAR(20)
        ,BelongsTo NVARCHAR(20)
        ,description NVARCHAR(30)
        ) AS go2
JOIN @tmp tmp ON tmp.Name = JSON_VALUE(arr.[value], '$.Name');

INSERT Info
    (EId, [Type], Label, Value)
SELECT tmp.id, go3.[Type], go3.Label, go3.Value
FROM OPENJSON(@json) arr
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(arr.[value], '$[0].Info') WITH (
        Type INT
        ,Label NVARCHAR(20)
        ,Value NVARCHAR(20)
        ) AS go3
JOIN @tmp tmp ON tmp.Name = JSON_VALUE(arr.[value], '$.Name');

INSERT Department
    (EId, Name, Street, Zipcode, City, Cvr, Contact, Email, Ean, Iref)
SELECT tmp.id, go4.Name, go4.Street, go4.Zipcode, go4.City, go4.Cvr, go4.Contact, go4.Email, go4.Ean, go4.Iref
FROM OPENJSON(@json) arr
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(arr.[value], '$.Department') WITH (
        Name NVARCHAR(20)
        ,Street NVARCHAR(20)
        ,Zipcode NVARCHAR(20)
        ,City NVARCHAR(20)
        ,Cvr NVARCHAR(20)
        ,Contact NVARCHAR(20)
        ,Email NVARCHAR(20)
        ,Ean NVARCHAR(20)
        ,Iref NVARCHAR(20)
        ) AS go4
JOIN @tmp tmp ON tmp.Name = JSON_VALUE(arr.[value], '$.Name');
```

Comment: I'm really close to making this work. I changed `Name` to `LocalNumber` since this is by construction unique. I'm only left with the `IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF` issue in the destination table. Can I "safely" just set IDENTITY_INSERT to ON/OFF before and after inserting?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to. The whole point is let the server generate the `IDENTITY` keys and `OUTPUT` them into the table variable, because otherwise you don't know what the key for each object is, so that you can use it in the other inserts. If `LocalNumber` is the primary key then you can simplify the whole thing by foreign-keying all the tables on `LocalNumber` and removing the table variable and the `OUTPUT` (because you know which child values go with which parent values)

Comment: When I ran your code, I got errors. If I have a destination table with and ID column named `EId` I get the `INDENTITY_INSERT` error. If I drop the table and create destination tables without the `EId` identity column, I get an `Invalid column name "EId"`.  Maybe I'm completely missing the point though...

Comment: Yeah I think you are: `EId` on the child tables should be a foreign key to the primary key on the `Employee` table. That primary key is the want we want to get hold of via `OUTPUT` because it's generated as an `IDENTITY`. So either you do it the way I have shown. Or you use `LocalNumber` as the primary key, and the child tables have a foreign key `Emp_LocalNumber` which refers to that, then you can insert the child tables by pulling `LocalNumber` on each query

Comment: Running your code with `Name` yields a dublicate error, as there's a dublicate value for some reason. Chaning everything to `LocalNumber` yields no errors, however only the `Employee` table is affected. The 4 remaining tables have `(0 rows affected)`

Comment: Found my mistake. Forgot to change `LocalNumber` to `INT` in the table variable decleration. Also had to remove the `[0]` in the `OPENJSON`.  Thank you very much for your patience and help.

Answer (score 0):

SCOPE_IDENTITY() returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column.

in your case, you're specifying the id in your INSERT statement,

meaning this "GId" column is not an identity column,

that's why you get null when you're calling SCOPE_IDENTITY()